# How to get attribute values from xml

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xml

I have some xml in this i have get attribute values ,i need to compare table id to get that attribute values .  Dis is my

Xml

```
 <response>

         <baccarat>

             <Game Gametype="Euro Baccarat 1" tableid="bc7ire5oi4uhetfd" studio="Manila-VIP">

                 <table type="low" min="1" max="100" >
                <betType type="side" min="1" max="100" />
                     <betType type="tie" min="10" max="30" />
                    <betType type="pair" min="10" max="22" />
                     <betType type="chip" chip="1,5,10,25,50,75,100" />
                     <betType type="default" chip="0" />
                 </table>

                 <table type="regular" min="10" max="250" >
                     <betType type="side" min="10" max="250" />
                     <betType type="tie" min="10" max="30" />
                     <betType type="pair" min="10" max="22" />
                     <betType type="chip" chip="1,5,10,25,50,100,250" />
                     <betType type="default" chip="2" />
                 </table>
                 <table type="high" min="50" max="500" >
                     <betType type="side" min="50" max="500" />
                     <betType type="tie" min="50" max="120" />
                     <betType type="pair" min="50" max="90" />
                     <betType type="chip" chip="1,5,10,25,50,100,500" />
                     <betType type="default" chip="4" />
                 </table>
                 <table type="vip" min="5" max="300" >
                     <betType type="side" min="5" max="300" />
                     <betType type="tie" min="5" max="100" />
                     <betType type="pair" min="5" max="75" />
                     <betType type="chip" chip="1,5,10,25,50,100,300" />
                     <betType type="default" chip="1" />
                 </table>
                 <table type="agent1" min="100" max="1000" >
                     <betType type="side" min="100" max="1000" />
                     <betType type="tie" min="100" max="600" />
                     <betType type="pair" min="100" max="450" />
                     <betType type="chip" chip="10,50,100,500" />
                     <betType type="default" chip="1" />
                 </table>
                 <table type="agent2" min="500" max="5000" >
                     <betType type="side" min="500" max="5000" />
                     <betType type="tie" min="500" max="1200" />
                     <betType type="pair" min="500" max="900" />
                     <betType type="chip" chip="10,50,100,500" />
                     <betType type="default" chip="1" />
                 </table>
                 <table type="private" min="5" max="300" >
                     <betType type="side" min="5" max="300" />
                     <betType type="tie" min="5" max="100" />
                     <betType type="pair" min="5" max="75" />
                     <betType type="chip" chip="1,5,10,25,50,100,300" />
                     <betType type="default" chip="1" />
                 </table>
             </Game>
```

```
<table type="low" min="1" max="100" >
    <betType type="side" min="1" max="100" />
    <betType type="tie" min="10" max="30" />
    <betType type="pair" min="10" max="22" />
    <betType type="chip" chip="1,5,10,25,50,75,100" />
    <betType type="default" chip="0" />
</table>

    <table type="regular" min="10" max="250" >
    <betType type="side" min="10" max="250" />
    <betType type="tie" min="10" max="30" />
    <betType type="pair" min="10" max="22" />
    <betType type="chip" chip="1,5,10,25,50,100,250" />
    <betType type="default" chip="2" />
</table>

    <table type="high" min="50" max="500" >
    <betType type="side" min="50" max="500" />
    <betType type="tie" min="50" max="120" />
    <betType type="pair" min="50" max="90" />
    <betType type="chip" chip="1,5,10,25,50,100,500" />
    <betType type="default" chip="4" />
</table>
    <table type="vip" min="5" max="300" >
    <betType type="side" min="5" max="300" />
    <betType type="tie" min="5" max="100" />
    <betType type="pair" min="5" max="75" />
    <betType type="chip" chip="1,5,10,25,50,100,300" />
    <betType type="default" chip="1" />
</table>
    <table type="agent1" min="100" max="1000" >
    <betType type="side" min="100" max="1000" />
    <betType type="tie" min="100" max="600" />
    <betType type="pair" min="100" max="450" />
    <betType type="chip" chip="10,50,100,500" />
    <betType type="default" chip="1" />
</table>
    <table type="agent2" min="500" max="5000" >
    <betType type="side" min="500" max="5000" />
    <betType type="tie" min="500" max="1200" />
    <betType type="pair" min="500" max="900" />
    <betType type="chip" chip="10,50,100,500" />
    <betType type="default" chip="1" />
</table>
<table type="private" min="5" max="300" >
    <betType type="side" min="5" max="300" />
    <betType type="tie" min="5" max="100" />
    <betType type="pair" min="5" max="75" />
    <betType type="chip" chip="1,5,10,25,50,100,300" />
    <betType type="default" chip="1" />
</table>
```

Dis my xml in dis xml i need to check table id if table id attribute is equal to dis bc8kuw8luk1dgfhy i need to go inside and get the values for all attributes example type is low i need to get that attributes of min max,like that i need to get all attributes values. now i am getting all values using log to display i need store that and get values where i want use .Dis my log inside the parser

```
 NSLog(@"elementName %@",elementName);
NSLog(@"attributeDict %@",attributeDict);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentelement=[elementName mutableCopy];
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"Game"]&&[[attributeDict objectForKey:@"tableid"] isEqualToString:@"bc8kuw8luk1dgfhy"])
    {
        isTableIdMatching = YES;
    }
    else if(isTableIdMatching && [elementName isEqualToString:@"table"]&&[[attributeDict objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"low"]){
        lowDict = attributeDict;
    }
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"table"]&& lowDict) {
        NSLog(@"attribut values of type low is---%@",lowDict);
        lowDict = nil;
    }else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Game"]){
        isTableIdMatching = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this its not working give some better way to get the values.i have spent time for last two days for dis.